# multiple select dropdown angular

Tags: angular, select, dropdown

I am using angular reactive form and I need an option to select multiple options from the dropdown. I am using multiple attributes to achieve this. The following is the code that I am using.

```
<select name="interface" multiple id="interface" class="form form-control"  formControlName="interface_name" id="interface_name" (change)="flood()">
          <option value=""><----select an interface-----></option>
          <option value="TP">TP</option>
          <option value="APOS">APOS</option>
          <option value="WS">WS</option>
          <option value="SHOPOS">SHOPOS</option>
          <option value="HHT">HHT</option>
          <option value="ESL">ESL</option>

</select>
```

The result that I am getting is here:

[image]

The result that I want is here. Please help me how can I achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Hey take a look into this package I have implemented it in the pass and worked 100% https://github.com/NileshPatel17/ng-multiselect-dropdown

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example in stackblitz?

Comment: sorry...can't do so restricted by company's policy.

Comment: A html multi-select looks like your first image, you can use angular material select https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#multiple-selection or another multiselect as Tiago say you (even make yourself a custom control)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, you can use multiselect bootstrap plugin. Here is good explanation how ti achieve it. http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/